# Jackson JsonBackReference Confusion

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I am using Spring MVC + Hibernate + Restful Web services + AngularJs to create a web application , 
i had a problem with the entities due to infinity inclusion , i resolved it with @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference .
 Now i don't have infinite loop anymore but the Json returned to the client is not what expected , two attributes are missing , and i don't have error messages

The DataBase relationships :

- Operator : One -- >  Sim      : Many
- Package  : One -- >  Sim      : Many
- Sim      : One -- >  Script   : Many
- Package  : Many-- >  Operator : Many

The Sim Object returned is

```
{  
   'id' :       ,
   'scriptList' : [...] 
}
```

Instead of

```
{
   'id' :       ,
   'scriptList' : [ ... ] , 
   'operator' :           ,
   'package' :           

}
```

## Here are my classes

### Sim.java

```
...
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "sim")
    public class Sim {


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "IDSIM")
        private Integer idsim;


        @JsonManagedReference("sim-script)
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "sim")
        private List<Script> scriptList=new ArrayList<>();

        @JsonBackReference("package-sim")
        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "IDPACKAGE", referencedColumnName = "IDPACKAGE")
        private Offre offre;

        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "IDOPERATOR", referencedColumnName = "IDOPERATOR")
        @JsonBackReference("operator-sim")
        private Operator operator;



        public Sim() {
        }

        public Sim(Integer idsim) {
            this.idsim = idsim;
        }

        public Integer getIdsim() {
            return idsim;
        }

        public void setIdsim(Integer idsim) {
            this.idsim = idsim;
        }


        public List<Script> getScriptList() {
            return scriptList;
        }

        public void setScriptList(List<Script> scList) {
            this.scriptList = scriptList;
        }


        public Package getPackage() {
            return package;
        }

        public void setPackage(Package Package) {
            this.offre = offre;
        }
        public Operator getOperator() {
            return operator;
        }

        public void setOperator(Operator operator) {
            this.operator = operator;
        }


    }
```

### Operator.java

```
 ...    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Operator")

    public class Operateur  {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "IDOPERATOR")
        private Integer idoperator;

        ...

        @JoinTable(name = "operator_package", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "IDOPERATOR", referencedColumnName = "IDOPERATOR")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "IDPACKAGE", referencedColumnName = "IDPACKAGE")})
        @ManyToMany
        private List<Package> packageList=new ArrayList<>();



        @JsonManagedReference("operator-sim")
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "operator")
        private List<Sim> simList =new ArrayList<>();

        public Operator() {
        }

        ...

        public List<Operator> getOperatorList() {
            return operatorList;
        }

        public void setPackageList(List<Package> packageList) {
            this.packageList = packageList;
        }


        public List<Sim> getSimList() {
            return simList;
        }

        public void setSimList(List<Sim> simList) {
            this.simList = simList;
        }
    }
```

### Package.java

```
...
@Entity
@Table(name = "package")

public class Offre {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "IDPACKAGE")
    private Integer idoffre;
    ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "packageList")
    private List<Operator> operatorList;



    @JsonManagedReference("package-sim")   
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "package")
    private List<Sim> simList=new ArrayList<>();

    public Package() {
    }

    ... 


    public List<Operator> getOperatorList() {
        return operatorList;
    }

    public void setOperatorList(List<Operator> operatorList) {
        this.operatorList = operatorList;
    }


    public List<Sim> getSimList() {
        return simList;
    }

    public void setSimList(List<Sim> simList) {
        this.simList = simList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you resolve it?